# How to hidden Umbral Key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

As umbral-doc define
[Main operation of Umbral KEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3OXf.png)

1. Alice use public Key encapsulaition, the K (key used for chacha20 encrypt) was genrated.
2. ReEncryption for shared to bob.
3. Final, Bob use privateKey get K and cipherText, decrypt cipherText get plainText.

My Question is:
**Final, Bob get *decrypt Key*,  so next time Bob can use *decrypt Key* decrypt cipherText without gather cFrags, also can send key to other(like clark), How to keep the secret.**

The umbral program guide like:

```py
from umbral import pre, keys, signing

# Generate Umbral keys for Alice.
alices_private_key = keys.UmbralPrivateKey.gen_key()
alices_public_key = alices_private_key.get_pubkey()

alices_signing_key = keys.UmbralPrivateKey.gen_key()
alices_verifying_key = alices_signing_key.get_pubkey()
alices_signer = signing.Signer(private_key=alices_signing_key)

# Generate Umbral keys for Bob.
bobs_private_key = keys.UmbralPrivateKey.gen_key()
bobs_public_key = bobs_private_key.get_pubkey()

# Generate Umbral keys for Clark.
clarks_private_key = keys.UmbralPrivateKey.gen_key()
clarks_public_key = clarks_private_key.get_pubkey()

# Encrypt data with Alice's public key.
plaintext = b'Proxy Re-Encryption is cool!'
ciphertext, capsule = pre.encrypt(alices_public_key, plaintext)

# Decrypt data with Alice's private key.
cleartext = pre.decrypt(ciphertext=ciphertext,
                        capsule=capsule,
                        decrypting_key=alices_private_key)

# Alice generates "M of N" re-encryption key fragments (or "KFrags") for Bob.
# In this example, 10 out of 20.
kfrags = pre.generate_kfrags(delegating_privkey=alices_private_key,
                             signer=alices_signer,
                             receiving_pubkey=bobs_public_key,
                             threshold=10,
                             N=20)


capsule.set_correctness_keys(delegating=alices_public_key,
                             receiving=bobs_public_key,
                             verifying=alices_verifying_key)

cfrags = list()           # Bob's cfrag collection
for kfrag in kfrags[:10]:
    cfrag = pre.reencrypt(kfrag=kfrag, capsule=capsule)
    cfrags.append(cfrag)    # Bob collects a cfrag

for cfrag in cfrags:
    capsule.attach_cfrag(cfrag)

bob_cleartext = pre.decrypt(ciphertext=ciphertext,
                            capsule=capsule,
                            decrypting_key=bobs_private_key)
assert bob_cleartext == plaintext

print(bob_cleartext)
```

Comment: 1. "privateKey encapsulaition" that's not how it works. Either you mean the public key or you mean decapsulation. 2. this diagram doesn't mention who knows what. If we have re-encryption then there is some sort of proxy server which is distinct from the machines Alice and Bob are working on.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming. [crypto.se] might be a better community for this question, but it needs clearer problem statement.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Tks, The first step use public Key,Sorry, I fixed it now.

Comment: I read Umbral whitepaper, Every data store in cloud use a random DEK decrypt as cipher text , but final bob will got the DEK and cipher text, means that others can got cipher text, if bob shared the DEK to clack, Clack use DEK to decrypt cipher text directly.

Comment: You're right, if Bob shares his decryption key with someone else they might be able to decrypt anything instead of Bob. There is no 100% protection from that. You can reduce the problem by making it harder for Bob to share. I.e. requiring Bob to log in (to a central system) using multi-factor authentication (sharing a cell phone is cumbersome) or somehow requiring Bob to use his TPM/Intel SGX on his machine to hold some keys.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks a lot.